# Does the part after BEQ execute if the flag EQ is not = 1

Tags: assembly, arm

If the flag EQ after SUBS is = to 0, does Routine1 execute? or does it have to be branched by BEQ (EQ flag has to be 1) to execute

.

I have the following code :

```
   Change                 
      SUBS R1, R1, #0x1
      BEQ  Routine 1
   Routine 1
      MOV R1, #0x10
      B       Change
```

.

Comment: Can you precise the memory layout? According to your code,  Routine 1 seems to be just after the BEQ in memory. In that case is Z flag is set, BEQ will branch to Routine 1. If not, your will go to next instruction that happens to be the start of Routine 1.

Comment: Alright, Awesome. I needed to confirm that. Thank you

Comment: This is described in the arm documentation, what part of the arm docs were you not clear on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing special about the label you use to implement a subroutine, it doesn't magically guard the code that follows it. Your branch here will architecturally behave the same irrespective of the condition codes.

From the processor's point of view, there are no functions or subroutines, just a sequence of instructions with (arbitrary) branches. Exceptions are different, these are slightly distinct (but you can still use the same range of instruction addresses for an exception and in normal code, even it it would be slightly weird)